# Why in LDA, n-components doesn't works properly?

Tags: scikit-learn, lda, linear-discriminant

I tried to use LDA and find a 3-channel output. But its output has just 2 channels.

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA

x = []
y = []
for i in range(len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        x.append([i,i,j,j])
        y.append(img[i][j])
y = np.array(y)
x = np.array(x)
y.shape,x.shape
lad = out = _ = ''
lda = LDA(n_components=3)
out = lda.fit(x, y).transform(x)
print(out.shape,y.shape,x.shape)
```

I used [i, i, j, j] because LDA asked me to have x with more features.

and printed output is:
`((392960, 2), (392960,), (392960, 4))`
but for out.shape I seek (392960,3)

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

The number of components in [`LinearDiscriminantAnalysis`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis) is always lower than the number of classes as it projects the data into an affine subspace of dimension at most the number of classes minus 1. It looks like your `y` has 3 classes.

Comment: Thank you, Sanjar Adilov, but no, my data had about 250 different classes, but I decided to use another algorithm in the end. Maybe you guessed that from x.shape, but it is just each node's x,y dimension, but I used them two times to avoid limitations based on LDA documentation.
BTW, Thank you very much.